# PHP define() function not work with unicode utf-8 characters

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

i work with php `define();` function and put value from MySQL database like this:

```
$options = DataAccess::FETCHLOAD("SELECT sign FROM " . OPTIONS . " WHERE 1");
define('_SIGN_',$options['0']['sign']);

echo _SIGN_;
```

now in ouuput is:

```
?????????????????????
```

without define:

```
echo $options['0']['sign'];
```

output worked :

```
تواصل معنا
```

all mysql result work with `utf-8` ouput, but when i work with define my result not in `utf-8`!!

how do fix this ?

Comment: What is the output if you make: `echo $options['0']['sign']`? Also your sure its not: `$options[0]['sign']`?

Comment: Did you see my answer? Does it work for you with that? If not try to assgin the string directly like: `define('_SIGN_',"تواصل معنا ");` and show what you get!

Comment: @Rizier123: You see my Cm?

Comment: Yep saw the comment. But if your looking through my answer update and you can confirm it then it isn't logical! Then you have to show my more code

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Also have you set your charset in your `*.php` file?

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>

<?php 

    $options['0']['sign'] = "تواصل معنا";
    define('_SIGN_',$options['0']['sign']);

    echo _SIGN_;

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Update after comment:

```
$options = DataAccess::FETCHLOAD("SELECT sign FROM " . OPTIONS . " WHERE 1");
echo $options['0']['sign'];  //You said that you here the output is "تواصل معنا"
define('_SIGN_',$options['0']['sign']);

echo _SIGN_;  //And here the output is "?????????????????????"
```

But this works for you:

```
define('_SIGN_',"تواصل معنا");
echo _SIGN_; //And here the output is "تواصل معنا"
```

This can't be! It's not locigal!

Comment: Sure! this worked. My Q is : when i retrieve data from database` define()` not work.

Comment: i found my problem: i put this code into `config.php` file and after include file to my page my code not work!!

Comment: You have to show my how you include the `config.php` file and where!

Comment: require $abspath .'/config.php'; Before `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head><body>PHP + HTML CODE</body></html>`

Comment: End's the file with `*.php` in which your including the `config.php`? Also show more code above the `define()` statement in the `config.php` file

Comment: new Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616370/php-uncode-utf-8-result-in-required-files