# php unicode UTF-8 result in required files

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

i add this `define()` function in my `config.php` file.

```
$options = DataAccess::FETCHLOAD("SELECT sign FROM " . OPTIONS . " WHERE 1");
define('_SIGN_',$options['0']['sign']);
```

Now, i `required` `config.php` file into my `index.php` page like this :

```
require $abspath .'/config.php';

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <?PHP echo _SIGN_; ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

now in output i have this result:

```
?????????????????????
```

worked result :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  $options = DataAccess::FETCHLOAD("SELECT sign FROM " . OPTIONS . " WHERE 1");
  define('_SIGN_',$options['0']['sign']);
  <?PHP echo _SIGN_; ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

output result :

```
تواصل معنا
```

how do fix this for show unicode UTF-8 when i required `config.php` ?!

Comment: What is the charset for that table in your database?

Comment: @Machavity: UTF-8. please see my edit.

Comment: @o-O And where did you set '$abspath' ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try after establishing connection to the database execute:

`set_charset ( "utf8")`

I use MySQLi and make it this way:

```
//-> conncecting to db
$mysqli = new mysqli ( $hostname, $username, $password, $db );

if ( $mysqli -> connect_errno ) {

    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . $mysqli -> connect_error;

}

// change character set to utf8
if ( ! $mysqli -> set_charset ( "utf8") ) {

    printf ( "Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist where did you set the variable `$abspath` ?

Then you have to put `<?php` and `?>` tags around your require statemet and in your config file around your php!

Now the example below works fine for me and is pretty much the same as yours!

config.php:

```
<?php

    $options['0']['sign'] = "تواصل معنا";  //$options = DataAccess::FETCHLOAD("SELECT sign FROM " . OPTIONS . " WHERE 1");
    define('_SIGN_', $options['0']['sign']);


?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php require 'config.php'; ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <?PHP echo _SIGN_; ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And the Output is:

```
تواصل معنا
```

Comment: This Wokred For me too. But not work with database retrieve data.